# Ubuntu 16.10 on Surface Pro 3 Crashes a lot

Tags: surface

I decided to try Ubuntu but this frequent crashes/freezing is killing me, I also noticed that when downloading large files on the internet like Steam games it freezes faster. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: I disabled wifi and started using a wired connection and I guess the problem seems got away, now I need to know how to fix my wifi drivers to not freeze my computer, I hope that someone can help. Thanks

Comment: It seems you correctly identified the issue. Now, I suggest you find out which WiFi adapter you have and then google it +Ubuntu (or Surface Pro 3 + Ubuntu). If you can't solve it on your own by reading then please open a new question and include hardware info.